# How to select 2nd bootstrap tab on load of page?

Tags: javascript, html, css

EDIT: So i ditched the whole thing and resorted to javascript with these new codes @Udara Kasun's code worked and it was close but not what I was trying to achieve. tried these codes for a while and i think i almost got it.

```
<script>    
function myFunction1()
{
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
       $('.nav-tabs li:nth-child(1) a').tab('show') 
    });
}
function myFunction2()
{
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
       $('.nav-tabs li:nth-child(2) a').tab('show') 
    });
}
function myFunction3()
{
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
       $('.nav-tabs li:nth-child(3) a').tab('show') 
    });
}
</script>

<li role="presentation" class="active" id="tabMenu1" onclick="myFunction1()">
    <a href="#tabZone" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" aria-controls="tab1">
        Zones
    </a>
</li>
<li role="presentation" id="tabMenu2" onclick="myFunction2()">
    <a href="#tabChapels" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" aria-controls="tab2">
        Chapels
    </a>
</li>
  <li role="presentation" id="tabMenu3" onclick="myFunction3()">
    <a href="#tabUnits" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" aria-controls="tab3">
        Units
    </a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to do like this?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.nav-tabs a:last').tab('show') ;
  var lastselectedtab = localStorage.getItem("ActiveTab");
  $('.nav-tabs a[href="'+(lastselectedtab==''?"#tabChapels":lastselectedtab)+'"]').tab('show');
});

$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
  var target = $(e.target).attr("href") // activated tab
  localStorage.setItem("ActiveTab", target);  
})
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script><script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div role="tabpanel"> 
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li role="presentation">
       <a href="#tabZone" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" aria-controls="tab1">Zones</a>
   </li>
   <li role="presentation">
       <a href="#tabChapels" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" aria-controls="tab2">Chapels</a>
   </li>
</ul>
<div id="tabContent1" class="tab-content" style="font-family:Arial Unicode MS;">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="tabZone"> 
        Content 1        
    </div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in active" id="tabChapels">
        Content 2
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Code pen Link
https://codepen.io/udarakasun/pen/YdyRRy

Comment: It works but the issue that I can't get around was that the last active tab will only be active like for example when I click the CHAPELS tab, upon refreshing the page, the CHAPELS tab will be automatically selected and same with the ZONES tab

Comment: I changed the answer

Comment: Sort of works ... but i ditched the whole thing and tried to use javascript

Answer (score 0):

Nobody seemed to care anymore haha anyways for those of you who are wanting to achieve the same thing that I wanted to, I've created a stupid and ingenious way but it works.

```
<script language="javascript">
<?php
    if(isset($_GET['tabName']))
    {
        if($_GET['tabName']=="TAB1")
        {
            echo "var tabNo=1;";
            $_SESSION['tabNo']=1;
        }
        elseif($_GET['tabName']=="TAB2")
        {
            echo "var tabNo=2;";
            $_SESSION['tabNo']=2;

        }
    }       
?>
function loadscript()
{

    $(document).ready(function()
    {           
        $('.nav-tabs li:nth-child('+<?php echo $_SESSION['tabNo'];?>+') a').tab('show') 
    });
}
function myFunction1()
{       
    var tabName="TAB1";         
    window.location.href = "panel_gkkmain.php?tabName=" + tabName;          
}
function myFunction2()
{
    $(document).ready(function()
        {
           $('.nav-tabs li:nth-child(2) a').tab('show') 
        }); 
    var tabName="TAB2";         
    window.location.href = "panel_gkkmain.php?tabName=" + tabName;  

}
function myFunction3()
{
    var tabName="TAB3";         
    window.location.href = "panel_gkkmain.php?tabName=" + tabName;

}
```

and for the body, you have to declare `onload="loadscript()"`

After that you'll need to add bootstrap components to your page. This can be done easier through ADOBE DREAMWEAVER.

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
<li role="presentation" class="active" onClick="myFunction1()">
    <a href="#home1" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" aria-controls="tab1">
        Zones
    </a>
</li>
<li role="presentation" onClick="myFunction2()">
    <a href="#paneTwo1" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" aria-controls="tab2">
        Chapels
    </a>
</li>
```